# read Dxf file with java

Tags: java, math, autocad, dxf

can we **read** with **calculating**  object surface as example of a drawing **autocad** forms using **java**? 
I found some package that can read and display the dxf file

Comment: thanks Alexey,that's mean there's no solution using java or c# ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with AutoCAD files and java, but per your comment regarding C#...You can use the AutoCAD .NET API with C# or VB.net.  There is also the ObjectARX library for C++.  These are shipped with AutoCAD and are typically used for building AutoCAD plugins.

If you don't have access to AutoCAD, or need to run your application outside of AutoCAD I'd suggest looking into [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendesign.com/).  They have libraries for manipulating Autodesk files outside of the Autodesk suites.

Comment: It's not very "Open" if having access to source code costs $ 37,500 and just using the SDKs costs at least $ 2,250 per year